# How to add UISWitch to few rows in UITable in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, ipad

I have a `UITableView` which contains so many rows.In my screen there can be `UISwitch` added for few rows in `UITableView`.Please tell me how can i do this?

- Should i create a custom cell with a `UISwitch` & show or hide the `UISwitch`.
- Should i add the UISwitch directly from the code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Any suggestions please?

**EDIT:**

I have tried this code but this does not work.

```
 SettingsCell *cell;

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SettingCell";

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [tableView
            dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
            forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault];
    [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
}

if(indexPath.row==2 || indexPath.row==3)
{
    cell.switch_value.hidden=false;
}
else
{
     cell.switch_value.hidden=true;

}
cell.label_text.text = [VALUES objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

Comment: as I did. I created a custom cell with UISwith and show or hide it depends on cell

Comment: I have edited my answer with some code example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a new cell then you should use that cell for only required rows. For rest of the rows you should not take pain of hiding the switch.

If you create `UISwitch`  directly from the code in `CellForRowAtIndexPath`, then you should take care while re-using the cell. If you use different identifier for both cell types, the show/hide problem will get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions work here : you can add an `UISwitch` in a `UITableViewCell` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` : be just careful to check that no previously created `UISwitch` exists before creating a new one.

The second solution consists in using a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass.
I prefer this solution because you don't have to cast your subviews or use `viewWithTag:` method, or even to check if your custom subview was already created.

You should create some simples subclasses, such as PickerCell, SwitchCell, TextFieldcell : thus you will have your own set of custom `UITableViewCell` subclasses ready to be used within all your projects.

Assuming you have registered your reuse identifier, try this :=

```
//  Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *SettingCellIdentifier = @"SettingCell";
    static NSString *StandardCellIdentifier = @"StandardCell";

   if (indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3) {

        SettingsCell *cell = (SettingsCell *)[tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SettingCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault];
        [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
        cell.label_text.text = [VALUES objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // Do whatever you want with the switch here

        return cell;
    }
    else 
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:StandardCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // instantiate a regular UITableViewCell
        cell.label_text.text = [VALUES objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't add the switch in cellForRowAtIndexPath - cells can be reused, and then you add it again? Or you have to make sure that you only add it when it's not there yet? That's going to go wrong ...

Comment: You don't have to add it multiple times since using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` allocates the cell only if you don't have one available yet.

Comment: But if you add it when you dequeued the cell you will get the problems I described - of course not when you create it in the cell awakeFromNib function, which is not what you wrote for solution 1.

Comment: I didn't explained in detail the todo list for the 1st solution, but yes in this case you are right, you need to test if your `UISwitch` subview already exists or not. The second method is thus easier. I have edited my answer in order to reflect the constraints of the 1st method, thanks :)